# jquery .show() and .hide() not working..!

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code the jquery show and jQuery hide functions are not working..
Though this is the basic thing ,i couldn't get through this for the past 1 hour..
I am unable to hide and show the div...
PLease help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sample</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).ready(function(){



            var fieldExample = $('#myTags');


            fieldExample.focus(function() {
                var div = $('div#showDiv').show();
                $(document).bind('focusin#showDiv click#showDiv',function(e) {
                    if ($(e.target).closest('#showDiv, #myTags').length) return;
                    $(document).unbind('#showDiv');
                    div.fadeOut('medium');
                });
            });
        $('div#showDiv').hide();

             })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="myTags"/>

  <div id="showDiv" style="height:200px;width:200px;background-color:red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: I'm debugging this in Fiddle, and I'm not actually sure what the intention is with the middle stuff with the binding/unbinding. I think you've overcomplicated matters a little.

Comment: I am trying to display a div on focus of the input box and i don't want the div to disappear when i click the inside the div..i.e the div should be visible.. and i want to hide it when the input is not in the focus and if i click the cursor outside the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $field = $('#myTags'),
        $div = $('.showDiv').hide();

    $field.focus(function () {
        $div.show();
    });
    $(document).on('focusin click', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.showDiv, #myTags').length) return;
        $div.fadeOut('medium');
    });

})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/myPFu/)

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){



        var fieldExample = $('#myTags');


        fieldExample.focus(function() {
            var div = $('div#showDiv');
             div.show(); //show div
            $(document).on('focusin,click','#showDiv',function(e) {
                if ($(this).closest(' #myTags').length) return;

                $('#showDiv').off('focusin,click');
                div.fadeOut('medium');
            });
        });
    $('div#showDiv').hide();

         })

</script>
```

reference **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**